# Adjust MIDI Note Volume

Tags: language-agnostic, midi

[I am doing this work in Java, but I think the question is language-agnostic.]

I have a MIDI Note On volume (called "data2," it's 0-127) that I am adjusting with a fader (0 to 127). The "math" I am using is simple:

```
newData2 = oldData2 * faderVolume / 127;
```

Zero works perfectly, and 127 does too, **but the volumes close to the bottom of the range are way too loud, especially the louder notes. What might be a different relationship than a linear one (in pseudo-code would be great)?** I will have to plug them into the code and try them, of course.

I realize that this question depends on the instrument that is playing the Note Ons (a BFD Kit in Ableton Live, which doesn't inform much), but maybe not and perhaps there's a standard way to adjust a Midi Note On volume with a fader.

Comment: There's a difference using float data and integer data (for calculation it makes a lot of difference). Is `newData2` an integer?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, yes, that's part of the problem, I'm seeing now. It's an integer. Could that account for the problem that I'm having, though?

Comment: Yes, because you miss out of the decimal values (which can affect your result).

Comment: Thanks @The Elite Gentleman, I'll try it out and ping ya back here.It's reasonable to convert everything to floats, do the math, and then do a `Math.round`, right?

Comment: See my solution, `Math.round` might not be a good idea since you need all the decimal points that the midi controller can understand.

Comment: MIDI data2 is 0-127 for real, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said on my comment, when playing with sound or audio or any audible technologies, rather use doubles or floats (depending on the hardware or API specifications).

You are returning an integer on `newData2`. Rather convert it to a double or float (for precision).

e.g.

```
float newData2 = (float)oldData2 * (float)faderVolume / (float)127;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to help, but I will have to try it out empirically. Just trying out some numbers, the difference is never greater than 1, although it's more than 10% of final note volume in about 15% of all combinations. If this doesn't work, I will need something more curvaceous.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is correct.  You are figuring up the note-on velocity relative to the fader in a linear fashion.  A couple notes...

The parameter you are adjusting is velocity.  This does not necessarily mean volume!  The two do have a correlation for most synths (including your drum kit in Ableton) but it might not be as volume related as you might think.

0-velocity is equivalent to note-off and will never play a sound.  I say this because if the difference between 0 and 1 is signficant, itmight be that volume isn't affect as much by the velocity parameter as you might think.

Finally, traditional mixer faders use logarithmic law.  You might experiment with this, but again I think you are barking up the wrong tree with volume.

There is a MIDI message for channel volume that you should use for volume, and that is CC 7.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Brad +1. Regarding barking and trees: unfortunately I cannot touch channel volume because my "faders" control the MIDI volumes of groups of notes that are playing through the same channel. Anyway, this is all working much better now that I've removed rounding problems caused by early casting. I might try a logarythmic relation, too, though...